# Is there any tool for regression model?

Tags: regression, model-fitting

I need to derive the linear/Quadratic equation from the set of examples. Is there any tool available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools which can help you do this.  I have started a list below:

1. [Excel Analysis Tool Pack](http://www.add-ins.com/Analysis_ToolPak.htm)
2. [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)
3. [FreeMat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/)
4. [R Project](http://www.r-project.org/index.html)