# Non-linear regression in C#

Tags: c#, math, machine-learning, statistics, regression

I'm looking for a way to produce a non-linear (preferably quadratic) curve, based on a 2D data set, for predictive purposes. Right now I'm using my own implementation of ordinary least squares (OLS) to produce a linear trend, but my trends are much more suited to a curve model. The data I'm analysing is system load over time.

Here's the equation that I'm using to produce my linear coefficients:

[image: Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) formula]

I've had a look at Math.NET Numerics and a few other libs, but they either provide *interpolation* instead of *regression* (which is of no use to me), or the code just doesn't work in some way.

Anyone know of any free open source libs or code samples that can produce the coefficients for such a curve?

Comment: This is precisely the result I'm looking for: http://www3.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+%7B1%2C82.96%7D%2C%7B2%2C86.23%7D%2C%7B3%2C87.09%7D%2C%7B4%2C84.28%7D%2C%7B5%2C83.69%7D%2C%7B6%2C89.18%7D%2C%7B7%2C85.71%7D%2C%7B8%2C85.05%7D%2C%7B9%2C85.58%7D%2C%7B10%2C86.95%7D%2C%7B11%2C87.95%7D%2C%7B12%2C89.44%7D%2C%7B13%2C93.47%7D

Comment: Another q with links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882009/is-there-any-tool-for-regression-model A relevant-looking codeproject thing: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadraticRegression.aspx

Comment: The former is a set of links to interpolation models, and the latter gives unusably incorrect / innacurate results, even after converting it to use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: The title is wrong. This is linear regression, because a polynomial can be expressed as a linear combination over the parameters. The accepted solution does exactly that: decomposes the polynomials to the product of a Vandermonde matrix and the parameter vector.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used the [MathNet.Iridium](http://www.mathdotnet.com/downloads/Iridium-2008-8-16-470.ashx?From=IridiumCurrentRelease) release because it is compatible with .NET 3.5 and VS2008. The method is based on the [Vandermonde](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Vandermonde%20matrix&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*MathWorld.VandermondeMatrix-) matrix. Then I created a class to hold my polynomial regression

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

public class PolynomialRegression
{
    Vector x_data, y_data, coef;
    int order;

    public PolynomialRegression(Vector x_data, Vector y_data, int order)
    {
        if (x_data.Length != y_data.Length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        this.x_data = x_data;
        this.y_data = y_data;
        this.order = order;
        int N = x_data.Length;
        Matrix A = new Matrix(N, order + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            A.SetRowVector( VandermondeRow(x_data[i]) , i);
        }

        // Least Squares of |y=A(x)*c| 
        //  tr(A)*y = tr(A)*A*c
        //  inv(tr(A)*A)*tr(A)*y = c
        Matrix At = Matrix.Transpose(A);
        Matrix y2 = new Matrix(y_data, N);
        coef = (At * A).Solve(At * y2).GetColumnVector(0);
    }

    Vector VandermondeRow(double x)
    {
        double[] row = new double[order + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= order; i++)
        {
            row[i] = Math.Pow(x, i);
        }
        return new Vector(row);
    }

    public double Fit(double x)
    {
        return Vector.ScalarProduct( VandermondeRow(x) , coef);
    }

    public int Order { get { return order; } }
    public Vector Coefficients { get { return coef; } }
    public Vector XData { get { return x_data; } }
    public Vector YData { get { return y_data; } }
}
```

which then I use it like this:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Vector x_data = new Vector(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        Vector y_data = new Vector(new double[] { 1.0, 1.4, 1.6, 1.3, 0.9 });

        var poly = new PolynomialRegression(x_data, y_data, 2);

        Console.WriteLine("{0,6}{1,9}", "x", "y");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            double x = (i * 0.5);
            double y = poly.Fit(x);

            Console.WriteLine("{0,6:F2}{1,9:F4}", x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Calculated coefficients of `[1,0.57,-0.15]` with the output:

```
    x        y
 0.00   1.0000
 0.50   1.2475
 1.00   1.4200
 1.50   1.5175
 2.00   1.5400
 2.50   1.4875
 3.00   1.3600
 3.50   1.1575
 4.00   0.8800
 4.50   0.5275
```

Which matches the [quadratic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic%20%5B%5B0,1%5D,%5B1,1.4%5D,%5B2,1.6%5D,%5B3,1.3%5D,%5B4,0.9%5D%5D) results from Wolfram Alpha.
[image: Quadratic Equation]
[image: Quadratic Fit]

**Edit 1**
To get to the fit you want try the following initialization for `x_data` and `y_data`:

```
Matrix points = new Matrix( new double[,] {  {  1, 82.96 }, 
               {  2, 86.23 }, {  3, 87.09 }, {  4, 84.28 }, 
               {  5, 83.69 }, {  6, 89.18 }, {  7, 85.71 }, 
               {  8, 85.05 }, {  9, 85.58 }, { 10, 86.95 }, 
               { 11, 87.95 }, { 12, 89.44 }, { 13, 93.47 } } );
Vector x_data = points.GetColumnVector(0);
Vector y_data = points.GetColumnVector(1);
```

which produces the following coefficients (from lowest power to highest)

```
Coef=[85.892,-0.5542,0.074990]
     x        y
  0.00  85.8920
  1.00  85.4127
  2.00  85.0835
  3.00  84.9043
  4.00  84.8750
  5.00  84.9957
  6.00  85.2664
  7.00  85.6871
  8.00  86.2577
  9.00  86.9783
 10.00  87.8490
 11.00  88.8695
 12.00  90.0401
 13.00  91.3607
 14.00  92.8312
```

Comment: I optimized and upgraded your answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12770686/1046374

Answer (score 12):

@ja72 code is pretty good. But I ported it on the present version of [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) (MathNet.Iridium is not supported for now as I understand) and optimized code size and performance (For instance, `Math.Pow` function is not used in my solution because of slow performance).

```cs
public class PolynomialRegression
{
    private int _order;
    private Vector<double> _coefs;

    public PolynomialRegression(DenseVector xData, DenseVector yData, int order)
    {
        _order = order;
        int n = xData.Count;

        var vandMatrix = new DenseMatrix(xData.Count, order + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            vandMatrix.SetRow(i, VandermondeRow(xData[i]));
        
        // var vandMatrixT = vandMatrix.Transpose();
        // 1 variant:
        //_coefs = (vandMatrixT * vandMatrix).Inverse() * vandMatrixT * yData;
        // 2 variant:
        //_coefs = (vandMatrixT * vandMatrix).LU().Solve(vandMatrixT * yData);
        // 3 variant (most fast I think. Possible LU decomposion also can be replaced with one triangular matrix):
        _coefs = vandMatrix.TransposeThisAndMultiply(vandMatrix).LU().Solve(TransposeAndMult(vandMatrix, yData));
    }

    private Vector<double> VandermondeRow(double x)
    {
        double[] result = new double[_order + 1];
        double mult = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= _order; i++)
        {
            result[i] = mult;
            mult *= x;
        }
        return new DenseVector(result);
    }

    private static DenseVector TransposeAndMult(Matrix m, Vector v)
    {
        var result = new DenseVector(m.ColumnCount);
        for (int j = 0; j < m.RowCount; j++)
        {
            double v_j = v[j];
            for (int i = 0; i < m.ColumnCount; i++)
                result[i] += m[j, i] * v_j;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public double Calculate(double x)
    {
        return VandermondeRow(x) * _coefs;
    }
}
```

It's also available on [github:gist](https://gist.github.com/3849678).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you want non linear regression. Even if you are using a quadratic function, it is still called linear regression. What you want is called multivariate regression. If you want a quadratic you just add a x squared term to your dependent variables.

Comment: Linear regression gives me a line. I've got no idea how to edit the equation I posted to do anything different. I want to get this kind of result: http://www3.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+%7B1%2C82.96%7D%2C%7B2%2C86.23%7D%2C%7B3%2C87.09%7D%2C%7B4%2C84.28%7D%2C%7B5%2C83.69%7D%2C%7B6%2C89.18%7D%2C%7B7%2C85.71%7D%2C%7B8%2C85.05%7D%2C%7B9%2C85.58%7D%2C%7B10%2C86.95%7D%2C%7B11%2C87.95%7D%2C%7B12%2C89.44%7D%2C%7B13%2C93.47%7D

Comment: Use the formula. But instead of x1 x2 use your x and x squared. If you still have problems I'll try and make an example calc in excel or pseudocode.

Comment: Wikipedia says "This term is distinct from multivariate linear regression, where multiple correlated dependent variables are predicted, rather than a single scalar variable." so I don't think multivariate regression is the correct term here because the OP is using a single dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53796.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122095301/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53796.html) to try get an idea about how it can be done.

Then [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63170/Least-Squares-Regression-for-Quadratic-Curve-Fitti) has a nice implementation that I think will help you.

Comment: That implementation didn't work for me. It gave completely incorrect results (0/1/0 for the coeffs) out of the box and after some tweaking was still completely innacurate. Nothing like the Wolfram Alpha results I discovered earlier. The math in the link you provided is beyond me, unfortunately.