# Implementing Cubic Spline Interpolation (PCHIP or MAKIMA) for 3D points in C#

Tags: c#, math, 3d, interpolation, spline

I wrote an application in C# which controls a camera through a 3D environment.
At the moment the camera follows a path which is defined as an array of points, where each point is defined as: x, y, z & rotation for each axis (everything is a float)
The camera position between those points are computed by linear interpolation every frame.

Because this leads to very clunky movement, I want to implement cubic spline interpolation instead.
There are many different algorithms, but so far I set my eyes on the following, since those feel "more correct", which means they don't overshoot:

- [Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial (PCHIP)](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/ref/pchip.html)
- [Modified Akima piecewise cubic Hermite interpolation (MAKIMA)](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/makima.html#mw_cc0c5239-ebe0-4fc7-ac39-f39077e687f3)

My biggest problem is, that I am absolutely not a mathematician and I can't read and understand the gibberish found online for their definitions, so I need help translating it into code.

---

**Constraints for the implementation**

- Algorithm should use either PCHIP or MAKIMA (I am open for other "correct" approaches though)
- Interpolated values must be a function of time (t from 0 to {points.Length})
- Must run for 3D points, not only 2D
- Should not contain any external libraries if possible

---

**Libraries**

I have checked the following, but they either don't support 3D points, or interpolation by time (and aren't intuitive to use either... not even talking about the license here):

- [Math.NET Numerics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Interpolation/CubicSpline.htm)
- [ALGLIB](https://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php)

---

Here is a small code stump which I came up with to demonstrate what I am looking for:

```
    static float[,] points = new float[,] {
        {10, 10, 10},
        {35, 5, 25},
        {15, 30, 15}
    };
    static int numberOfPoints = points.Length / 3; // dividing for each stored float value per point: only x, y, z for simplification

    static void Main()
    {

        List<float[]> pointsWithInterpolation = new(); // holding both known and interpolated points
        float stepSize = 0.1f; // step size for t

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints - 1; i++)
        { // loop for each spline segment
            pointsWithInterpolation.Add(new float[] { points[i, 0], points[i, 1], points[i, 2] }); // add an allready known point to the list
            for (float t = stepSize; t < 1f; t += stepSize)
            { // should run (1 / {stepSize} - 2) times
                float[] interpolatedPoint = Interpolate(i + t);
                pointsWithInterpolation.Add(interpolatedPoint); // add an interpolated point to the list
            }
            if (i == numberOfPoints - 1)
            { // add the very last point if we have finished the last segment
                pointsWithInterpolation.Add(new float[] { points[i + 1, 0], points[i + 1, 1], points[i + 1, 2] }); // add an allready known point to the list
            }
        }
    }

    private static float[] Interpolate(float t)
    {
        // point indexes
        int p1 = (int)t;
        int p2 = p1 + 1;
        int p0 = p1 == 0 ? 0 : p1 - 1; // if there are no previous point, set it to the first one
        int p3 = p2 == numberOfPoints - 1 ? p2 : p2 + 1; // if there are no following points, set it to the last one
        
        float x0 = points[p0, 0];
        float x1 = points[p1, 0];
        float x2 = points[p2, 0];
        float x3 = points[p3, 0];

        float y0 = points[p0, 1];
        float y1 = points[p1, 1];
        float y2 = points[p2, 1];
        float y3 = points[p3, 1];

        float z0 = points[p0, 2];
        float z1 = points[p1, 2];
        float z2 = points[p2, 2];
        float z3 = points[p3, 2];

        float x, y, z;
        /* black magic hocus pocus happening here
        x = ???;
        y = ???;
        z = ???;
         */
        float[] point = new float[] { x, y, z };
        return point;
    }
```

So the question is: what is the formula for solving for x/y/z (the formula should be the same for each variable, but they use different variables).
Yes I know, this results in a constant number of interpolated points between the "real" ones, even if the distance of segments widely varies - I will tackle the issue of constant speed separately.
If I am not mistaken, every interpolation between p1 and p2 needs 4 values, so I set p0 equal to p1 for the very first segment and p3 equal to p2 for the last one to make up for non-existant points.
I haven't performance optimized the code, so I (hopefully) make it more clear/easy to understand what I try to do.
Of course I would also be thankful for code in other languages, as long as it fulfils the implementation constraints and doesn't use functions which aren't available in C# (and also no assembler please lmao)

Comment: Related answer on use of [cubic splines with Math.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211208/13813219)

Comment: @JAlex Math.NET CubicSplines only support 2D points

Comment: see [Piecewise interpolation cubic example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22806242/2521214) I think its better for your task ... (its a CATMULL-ROM SPLINE curve btw...)

Comment: @Spektre thanks, I tried Catmull-Rom splines first too, after I have seen it on a nice YouTube video how to implement it.
For anyone interested: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_aJGUTePYo)
It seems that Catmull-Rom splines have a TAU parameter, which would control the smoothness of the curve, but I haven't seen any implementation where this is involved as a parameter directly (probably already been implemented into the formular themselves).
If anyone has an idea how to implement Catmull-Rom with TAU, it would nice to have the solution here too ^^

Comment: Figured out a solution for my problem, even though it's neither perfect nor super optimized.
For this I use the Math.NET Numerics library mentioned (since it has a permissive MIT license) and avoid the 2D limitation by making a spline for each axis, plotting time as X and the axis in question as Y.
I think the method/parameter naming of those CubicSpline functions is off, and that's why some much confusion has arisen... might contact the devs about that :)
Once I am done with being sick I will make a detailled description and video about the solution, so others must not struggle as well.